# Quickest method of copy-pasting range of cells in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

**Background**

I wrote script for copying range of cells from one document to another. It works correctly. But depending on volume of data it could run for 10+ minutes. Which is odd, because manual copy-pasting of this data without script will took 2 minutes. I ran some tests that revealed most time-consuming piece of code that needs to be speed up

**Question**

What is the quickest method of copying range of cells from one Google Spreadsheet document to another? Or how should I change my code to speed it up?

```
  // Copying 1st batch of data
  var srcLastRow = srcSheet1.getLastRow();
  var srcLastCol = srcSheet1.getLastColumn();
  var srcRange = srcSheet1.getRange(2, 1, srcLastRow-1, srcLastCol);
  var transfValues = srcRange.getValues();
  destSheet.getRange(destLastRow + 1,1,srcLastRow-1, srcLastCol).setValues(transfValues);
```

**Appendix**

And here is full script, that runs correctly but slow, just in case

```
function sborka() {

  // Destination sheet variables
  var destSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var destSheet = destSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("destination");
  
  // Source sheet variables
  var srcSpreadSheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxx');
  var srcSheet1 = srcSpreadSheet1.getSheetByName("source 1");
  var srcSpreadSheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ууууууу');
  var srcSheet2 = srcSpreadSheet2.getSheetByName("source 2");
  
  // Clear all except 1st row with headers
  var destLastRow = destSheet.getLastRow();
  destSheet.deleteRows(2,destLastRow)
  
  // What is last row in destination sheet?
  var destLastRow = destSheet.getLastRow(); 

  // Copying 1st batch of data
  var srcLastRow = srcSheet1.getLastRow();
  var srcLastCol = srcSheet1.getLastColumn();
  var srcRange = srcSheet1.getRange(2, 1, srcLastRow-1, srcLastCol);
  var transfValues = srcRange.getValues();
  destSheet.getRange(destLastRow + 1,1,srcLastRow-1, srcLastCol).setValues(transfValues);

  // What is last row in destination sheet now?
  var destLastRow = destSheet.getLastRow(); 
  
  // Copying 2nd batch of data
  var srcLastRow = srcSheet2.getLastRow();
  var srcLastCol = srcSheet2.getLastColumn();
  var srcRange = srcSheet2.getRange(2, 1, srcLastRow-1, srcLastCol);
  var transfValues = srcRange.getValues();
  destSheet.getRange(destLastRow + 1,1,srcLastRow-1, srcLastCol).setValues(transfValues);

  // Done
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  var srcSheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var destSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("destination ss id");

  //Copy Source Sheet
  srcSheet1.copyTo(destSS);
  var newSrcSheet1 = destSS.getSheetByName("Copy of "+srcSheet1.getName());
  Logger.log(newSrcSheet1);

  //Copy range
  var destSheet = destSS.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var srcLastRow = newSrcSheet1.getLastRow();
  var srcLastCol = newSrcSheet1.getLastColumn();
  var srcRange = newSrcSheet1.getRange(2, 1, srcLastRow-1, srcLastCol);
  srcRange.copyTo(destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow() + 1,1));

  //Delete Sheet
  destSS.deleteSheet(newSrcSheet1);
```

- I copied first the source sheet to the destination spreadsheet. The name of the copied sheet will be "Copy of [original sheet name]". [Refer to Sheet.copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)
- Then, I copied the range from the new source sheet to the destination sheet using [Range.copyTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)
- Lastly, I deleted the new source sheet.

Comment: Thanks! Will test

Comment: No, it tells "Exception: Target range and source range must be on the same spreadsheet" =(

Comment: Sorry for that, i updated my answer. Please compare if this solution will be faster compared to your current implementation

Comment: Thank you! Will test little bit later. Currently testing a little different solution with IMPORTRANGE function